# How to display structure of PHP variables in Structure panel?

Tags: php, phpstorm

Say I have a deep, standalone object (not inside any class), like:

```
$mockedData = (object)array(
    'user'      => new MockedUser(),
    'templates' =>
        array(),
    'data' =>
        array(
            'user' =>
                (array(
                    'Model' =>
                        (array(
                            'mainTable' => 'users',
 (...)
```

and my cursor is on last line (`'mainTable' => 'users',`).

How can I see the structure of this object? 
So I know that I'm currently at: `$mockedData->data->user->Model->mainTable`.

At the moment all I see on my Structure panel is this:
[image]

Which is not helpful at all. I'd expect Structure panel to display all variables like it does for JS files:
[image]

How can I make it work same way for PHP? Perhaps there is a plugin for that?

Comment: Click on `(f)` button to include class fields/properties as well; `<C>` for constants. If some class field is an instance of a class -- Structure panel will not show its sub-structure. I'm just not sure what exactly you wish to see there (the code sample is not clear enough for me -- maybe try mocking it-- use MS Paint/Photoshop and add the missing info to have the feel of what's required).

Comment: It's very simple: I wish to see `$mockedData` in Structure, and be able to expand it, just like in second screenshot, where I expanded a JS variable `testResponses`.

Answer (score 0):

What is `$mockedData` -- ordinary variable?

- Global variables are not displayed in Structure window for few years now; local -- never were displayed at all.
- For class field/property use `(f)` button.

In any case -- structure of variables/fields is now shown for PHP.

Feel free to submit Feature Request ticket to the [Issue Tacker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WI).